Why iam unable to see event stream in MCP(marketing cloud personalization) though the sitemap code is correct. is it because of cookies cache issues
Is it because of cache need s to be cleared every time
If so what is the best way to clear the cache every time for a person who is working with MCP.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

With this limited information it's difficult to explain why evenstream is not showing in personlization. I would say please use debug to identify if there are any potential issues
SalesforceInteractions.setLoggingLevel('DEBUG'); 

